# CSS stylesheet doesn't work in ASP.NET Core (for page background and texbox css style)

Tags: css, asp.net-core

I created `customStyle.css` file in `wwwroot/css` folder as below:

```
.custominput {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-radius: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.mainPic {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,0),rgba(255,255,255,0)),url("publicimage/mainbackgroundpic.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;}
```

Also I put required link in my layout.cshtml file like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/customStyle.css" type="text/css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

but it doesn't work! Would you please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking the CSS file path? It might be pointing to the wrong place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css file not found - asp.net core web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854334/css-file-not-found-asp-net-core-web-application)

Comment: @rawnewdlz Thanks for your reply but before asked my question I checked that mentioned post. I checked every thing :(

Comment: @Re Salehi can you post your layout page code shortly to understand your linkup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The styles or scripts inside wwwroot is governed by a special method inside `Configure` method in `Startup.cs` class.

That method is **UseStaticFiles()**. See below screenshot:

[image]

Arrange the methods exactly mentioned in the screenshot and then give it a try.

**NOTE:** I am using .NET Core v3.1 (Long time support). If you have lower version then please make sure you add your **app.UseStaticFiles()** before **app.UseRouting()** method.